# Payment info from SCCAPIResponse

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6, square-connect

Is there any way to obtain payment info from SCCAPIResponse using the Connect API?  If not, this is very disappointing API, seems half baked...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Transaction APIs](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2/?q=client#endpoint-listtransactions) to return the payment info. In the [response object](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2/?q=client#type-transaction) there will be a property called `client_id` that you can use to match up the responses.

You cannot query by `client_id` at this moment, but it is a pain point that we are addressing.

Comment: Thanks, It would helpful to be able to at least return the payment total so our app info can be updated easily.  Otherwise, all the Connect API really does is eliminate rekeying the amount...

Comment: Well you initiate the request with an amount, is it possible to use that as your payment total?

Comment: Of course that is a possibility with our contractor apps.  However, our salon app users typically use your tip feature so the amount would include the tip.  Is there any way for you to use a "error code" to return the amount charged?

Comment: Sorry, not at this time. I recommend you using the REST end points to get the additional info

Answer (score 0):

SCCAPIResponse also includes TransactionID, which is the ID of the transaction generated by Square's server (if the transaction was successfully processed online). You can use this ID to get details of the transaction with the [RetrieveTransaction](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2#endpoint-retrievetransaction) endpoint.

Comment: Yes that is true, but we want to avoid the overhead, expense and liability of maintaining a server to store the credentials for our thousands of users.  We simply need the amount charged returned so we can update our apps.  Frankly, if we have to go that route it would make more sense to partner with a payment processor that offers revenue opportunities...